# IoT edge device does not send the messages to IoT hub despite it is connected to

Tags: azure, node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have deployed IoT edge device on Raspberry Pi 3.

I have three modules

- edgeAgent
- edgeHub
- Node-RED

All successfully run.

In the node-red I have some message processing and sending it to IoT edge through node-red module. I have already did so, but this time I faced the problem I could not solve for days.

I tried everything from updating the everything, I also did `iotedge config apply` because there was similar problem here with such a simple solution.

I have set the route when configuring the modules:

```
FROM /messages/modules/nodered/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream
```

and tried this as well:

```
FROM /messages/modules/nodered/outputs/ INTO $upstream
```

I tried to get the logs of my modules, although I was receiving

```
Error grabbing logs: log message is too large (168194932 > 1000000)
```

The `sudo iotedge check` give me the following (there are some warnings and errors with connection to the hub):

```
Configuration checks (aziot-identity-service)
---------------------------------------------
√ keyd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ certd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ tpmd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ identityd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ daemon configurations up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ identityd config toml file specifies a valid hostname - OK
√ aziot-identity-service package is up-to-date - OK
√ host time is close to reference time - OK
√ preloaded certificates are valid - OK
√ keyd is running - OK
√ certd is running - OK
√ identityd is running - OK
√ read all preloaded certificates from the Certificates Service - OK
√ read all preloaded key pairs from the Keys Service - OK
√ check all EST server URLs utilize HTTPS - OK
√ ensure all preloaded certificates match preloaded private keys with the same I                                                                                                                                                            D - OK

Connectivity checks (aziot-identity-service)
--------------------------------------------
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub AMQP port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub HTTPS / WebSockets p                                                                                                                                                             ort - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub MQTT port - OK

Configuration checks
--------------------
√ aziot-edged configuration is well-formed - OK
√ configuration up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
√ configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - OK
√ aziot-edge package is up-to-date - OK
√ container time is close to host time - OK
‼ DNS server - Warning
    Container engine is not configured with DNS server setting, which may impact connectivity to IoT Hub.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting DNS server per module in the Edge deployment.
‼ production readiness: logs policy - Warning
    Container engine is not configured to rotate module logs which may cause it run out of disk space.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-logs for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting log policy per module in the Edge deployment.
‼ production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeAgent module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeAgent directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
‼ production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Warning
    The edgeHub module is not configured to persist its /tmp/edgeHub directory on the host filesystem.
    Data might be lost if the module is deleted or updated.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-storage-host for best practices.
√ Agent image is valid and can be pulled from upstream - OK
√ proxy settings are consistent in aziot-edged, aziot-identityd, moby daemon and config.toml - OK

Connectivity checks
-------------------
× container on the default network can connect to upstream AMQP port - Error
    Container on the default network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:5671
× container on the default network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - Error
    Container on the default network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:443
× container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream AMQP port - Error
    Container on the azure-iot-edge network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:5671
× container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - Error
    Container on the azure-iot-edge network could not connect to dc-hub-rnd.azure-devices.net:443
27 check(s) succeeded.
4 check(s) raised warnings. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
4 check(s) raised errors. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
2 check(s) were skipped due to errors from other checks. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
```

Are there anyone who could have faced similar issue?

Comment: Hi @Arseniy Sleptsov, have you looked at this resource which provides [Troubleshooting steps for IoT Edge Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?view=iotedge-1.4). Refer the [Check container logs for issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?view=iotedge-1.4#check-container-logs-for-issues) and utilize the [UploadModuleLogs direct method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-retrieve-iot-edge-logs?view=iotedge-1.4#upload-module-logs) to push logs onto Azure portal.

Comment: You might also have to keep an eye on available memory on your Pi and [Clean up container logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?view=iotedge-1.4#clean-up-container-logs). Can you provide any resources on how you have developed your node-red Azure IoT Edge module? Did the routing ever work on this module?

Comment: Your second route won't work because you need an asterisk after the /outputs/ - see this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-1.4#source

Comment: Your device cannot connect to upstream. You should check first the network connection and firewall settings on your OS. Also, you can check the module outputs using **`iotedge logs <module name>`**